# treat missing data inside multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

problem is: add missed " ] " brackets at end of data for all columns except columns of  ID and z, if the backtick does not excite at end of data for each column as shown below

P.S>  dataframe contains multiple columns from x,y,a,b,c,d ......... etc. until z and the solution should deal with multiple columns

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['EF407412','KM043272']
                   , 'x': ['[2788, 3140, 4836','[539, 906, 1494, 1932, 2029,7001']
                   , 'y': ['[1408, 1572, 2277','[1,10000]']
                   , 'z': ['[1408, 1572, 2277]','[1,10000]']
                   # df dataframe containes N colemans x,y,z,a,b,c ......etc more than 100 colemans 
                   })
```

[image]

Comment: I've never used it but I would look into .applymap(). You can pass a function to it. That function would do something like: check the last value in the 'cell' and if its a ']' then return the value else return the value with with a ']' appended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is only `ID` and `z` columns that you want to skip, try this:

```
dfcut = dftest[[col for col in dftest if col != 'ID' and col != 'z']]
dfcut = dfcut.applymap(lambda cell: cell + ']' if cell[-1] != ']' else cell)
```

You can then insert newly edited columns to `dftest` as follows:

```
dftest[[col for col in dfcut.columns]] = dfcut
```

Comment: Thanks, @NuriTaş Can you please update "dftest" dataframe by the ouput of your code ?

Comment: I've added that part

Comment: this part not working 
 dftest[[col for col in dfcut.columns]] = dfcut

Comment: a small typo fixed

Comment: @SomeDude No, that's the reason I created another dataframe called `dfcut`

Answer (score 0):

With `apply` and `str.replace` which IMO is much better performing:

You basically look for the pattern that begins with '[' and has digits and spaces and commas but doesn't end with ']' with a negative look ahead and replace it with the captured value + ']'.

```
dftest.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(
    pat=r'^([[\d\s,]+(?!\])$)', repl=lambda m: m.group(1) + ']', regex=True))
```

With `applymap` (not so performant):

```
dftest.astype(str).applymap(
    lambda x: x + ']' if ~(x.endswith(']')) & (x.startswith('[')) else x)
```

output:

```
          ID                     x                                   y                   z
0   EF407412                   [2788, 3140, 4836]   [1408, 1572, 2277]  [1408, 1572, 2277]
1   KM043272    [539, 906, 1494, 1932, 2029,7001]            [1,10000]           [1,10000]
```

Comment: Super Thanks @SomeDude , your code is the best 